# Bash: Capturing Output from a curl command and mapping Key Values from the output to new Key-value pairs

Tags: bash, shell, curl, ksh

a curl command gives me a JSON output as follows:- `[{"Description":"","Value":"bc","Key":"a"},{"Description":"","Value":"ef","Key":"d"},...]`

Now I want to capture the values of only "Key" & "Value" in such a way that it if I perform `echo $a` it gives "bc", `echo $d` it gives "ef" etc.

Note: I am absolutely new in shell scripting/bash, thus this question

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` to parse the array and obtain the necessary value.

`echo '[{"Description":"","Value":"bc","Key":"a"},{"Description":"","Value":"ef","Key":"d"}]' | jq '.[] | select(.Key == "d").Value'`

This Should give you "ef" and,

`echo '[{"Description":"","Value":"bc","Key":"a"},{"Description":"","Value":"ef","Key":"d"}]' | jq '.[] | select(.Key == "a").Value'`

Will give you "bc"

You can replace the `echo` with your curl statement.

More about jq : https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: On top of this answer (which I upvoted), if you actually expect values without quotes, add the `-r` flag when invoking `jq`

Comment: @BlackPearl Thank you for the help. But for security reasons I am not able to install 'jq' here in my system. Also the output of the curl command may change, so I won't be sure about the keys or values..So need to write it and map it in such a way that if I perform echo $a it will give "bc", echo $d it will give "ef" and so on!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the job :

```
dataString='[{"Description":"","Value":"bc","Key":"a"},{"Description":"","Value":"ef","Key":"d"},...]'
while read value key; do
    echo "key: '$key', value : '$value'"
done < <(echo "$dataString" | sed 's/},{/\n/g' | tr -d '[]{}"' | tr ':' ',' | cut -d',' -f 4,6 --output-delimiter=' ')
```

Details :

- `dataString` is the output of `curl`
- the whole `(echo "$dataString"....)` simply turns `$dataString` into :

  bc a

  ef d
- the `<(...)` construct is a [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) . It allows reading the output of a command with the same method you'd be reading from a file